# Finding f(x) for a Riemann Sum - having trouble factoring out 'n'.

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

SE,

I've been given this problem to evaluate: [the problem[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbywU.png)

And here's my attempt at a solution: [I'm getting stuck at creating f(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLYcQ.jpg)

I've added the step numbers for reference, and hope to be given a push in the right direction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

\begin{align}
\frac{i}{n^2+i^2} = \frac{i}{1+(i/n)^2}\frac{1}{n^2}= \frac{(i/n)}{1+(i/n)^2}\frac{1}{n}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. I see how you utilized manipulation of the numerator to obtain $n^-1$.